# How to create Alarm to be play every 30 minutes in PHP

Tags: javascript

How to create Alarm to be play every 30 minutes in PHP ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function closeWindow() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    window.close();
    }, 1800000);
    }

    window.onload = closeWindow();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<audio controls autoplay="autoplay">

<source src="apple_ring.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

Comment: Wait, this is NOT related to PHP. It's just HTML & JavaScript. Also, if you're running this in mobile, it won't work, as modern browser blocked audio autoplay. Furthermore, 30000 is milliseconds (i.e. 30 seconds).  Last, remember to close your `<audio>` tag.

Comment: 30 mins is `1800000` not `30000`

Comment: Ok good, but how to refresh and play audio every 30 minutes ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove all the close window, stuff and try this.

```
<audio id="alarmAudio" controls autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="apple_ring.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script> 
    var alarm = document.getElementById("alarmAudio");

    setInterval(function(){
        alarm.play(); 
    }, 1800000);        
</script>
```

Comment: i think you don't have to set the audio to autoplay since it should be `played after 30 minutes` and not `play it first then replay after 30 minutes`